# Extract from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have an ajax call that returns JSON data (Data Attached).
After converting the data into String, this is how it looks like:

```
{
   "shipments":[
      {
         "companyName":"TriStar Inc.",
         "shipmentDate":null,
         "transMode":"NDAY",
         "paid":true,
         "delDate":null,
         "custRefInfo":{
            "customerName":"DAISY N.",
            "customerZip":"90544"
         },
         "orderStatus":true
      },
      {
         "companyName":"Carbo Box",
         "shipmentDate":null,
         "transMode":"COUR",
         "paid":true,
         "delDate":null,
         "custRefInfo":{
            "customerName":"TOM K",
            "customerZip":"07410"
         },
         "orderStatus":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Now when I print the JSON response in Firefox, it looks like:

```
[Object { companyName="TriStar Inc.", shipmentDate=null, transMode="NDAY", more...}, Object { companyName="Carbo Box", shipmentDate=null, transMode="COUR", more... } ]
```

My question is, how do I extract companyName and customerName field out of this response. The following isnt working:

```
 load: function(response){
        for(var i in response){
             console.log(response.shipments[i].companyName);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you get a string that is json, you need to parse it first.

`var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

now you have a proper object literal, and you can access it normally

`var shipments = obj.shipments;`

`shipments` is now a javascript array...

```
for(var i = 0; i < shipments.length; i++){
    console.log(shipments[i].companyName);
}
```

note you should not use the `for(var i in x)` construct on arrays.

Comment: Thanks hvgotcodes, it worked perfect. Could you please explain why for(var i in x) shouldnt be used to arrays?

Comment: its meant to be used for traversing the keys in an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.shipments[i].companyName
```

Comment: Hi ron, it didnt work. I got: TypeError: response.shipments[i] is undefined

Comment: Can you post your javascript?

Comment: Hi Ron, I update the javascript for loop in the question. posting it here as well:  load: function(response){
  for(var i in response){
             console.log(response.shipments[i].companyName);
  }

Comment: The first Answer (above mine) looks correct. Have you tried it?