# how do get to the inside of this list? also maybe a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
(
    {"resultList":
        [
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":12345, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1326258000000), "adEndDate":new Date(1326258001000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":12345, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1326171600000), "adEndDate":new Date(1326171601000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":7, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325480410000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325536200000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":4, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325433601000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325394001000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":3, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325430001000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325433600000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":2, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325426401000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325430000000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":1, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325422801000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325426400000)}, 
            {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":5, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325394002000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325440800000)}
        ], 

        [
            "totalRecords":0
        ], 

        [
            "pages":0
        ], 

        [
            "currentPage":0
        ], 

        [
            "pageSize":20
        ]
    }
)
```

This is the result I get when I call a json. Can someone help me with how to get into this?

I need to extract compSymbol, secId, name, adStart, adEnd

How do I extract them all using a for loop?

I was using:

```
for(var key in value)
{
    this.createRow(t, value[0].adEndDate, value[0].adStartDate...
}
```

Then I realize that it would need integers...

Please help!!

*EDIT* I do not need the totalRecords, pages, currentPage, pageSize, I only need whats inside resultList

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ /*list[i] = value, i = key*/ .... }`

Comment: this same question gets asked over and over.  I just answered one almost exactly similar yesterday.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902846/extract-from-ajax-response/8903772#8903772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{"resultList": [
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":12345, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1326258000000), "adEndDate":new Date(1326258001000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":12345, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1326171600000), "adEndDate":new Date(1326171601000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":7, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325480410000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325536200000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":4, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325433601000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325394001000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":3, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325430001000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325433600000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":2, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325426401000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325430000000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":1, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325422801000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325426400000)}, 
        {"compSymbol":"OTCM", "secId":5, "inserterName":"Bob", "adStartDate":new Date(1325394002000), "adEndDate":new Date(1325440800000)}
    ], 
    "totalRecords":0
    "pages":0
    "currentPage":0
    "pageSize":20
}
```

This is probably what your data actually looks like.  So to get the result list do this, first parse the json, there are several ways of doing this.  1 thing to do is just simple

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Next access the results list with a dot separator.

```
var myResults = myObj.resultList;
```

Now your `myResults` object is an array of json objects.  A very simple access would look like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myResults.length; i++) {
    alert(myResults[i].inserterName); // alerts Bob on all the rows because of your data :)
}
```

And there you go

---

Just so were straight, if your data looked like the one you provided, its invalid :(

Comment: Anything is better than eval. Modern browsers have JSON.parse: `var myObj = JSON.parse(string)`, and older browsers have json libraries that can be used. After parsing, the rest is the same

Comment: @Jim Hence i said the easiest way.  JSON.parse doesnt work on IE 7 or 8 (as far as i can tell i get errors every time).  I did not want to bring in the $.parseJSON either because that has an external library..

Comment: yeah, but json2 is available, without requiring all of jQuery, and should be preferred. Evaling a remote string is a massive security risk, and even with the ease, I would never suggest using it.

Comment: Ok i looked and agree.  I changed the answer to use JOSN.parse.

Comment: ya sorry, i added those [] for readibilty forgot to remove them.. in "JSON.parse(string)" what is this string?

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid JSON:

```
 {"resultList":
        [
        //...
        ], 
        [
        //...
        ], 
        [
        //...
        ], 
        [
        //...
        ], 
        [
        //...
        ]
    }
```

The contents of `resultList` are neither object literal nor an array. It is just a bunch of comma-separated array literals. Also the whole object is enclosed with parentheses (`()`), which never appear in valid JSON (maybe only a formatting issue).

This is how it should look like:

```
 {"resultList": [
        [
        //...
        ], 
        [
        //...
        ], 
    ]
}
```

Note the extra opening and closing square brackets. Now the `resultList` property has an array value, and each element of that array is an array itself.